# Best way to Retrieve , Encrypt and Update millions of records to MySQL using Java 8

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, performance, java-8, large-data

We have requirement to read around 10 millions of records from MySQL DB , Encrypt the records and update the fields back with the encrypted values.
How it can be implemented in a most efficient way.

**1** : Field Level encryption from MySQL DB using AES_ENCRPTY : As per my understanding AES_ENCRYPT will work effectively with varbinary , but our fields are varchar only.
So ruled out this option

**2** : Bulk insertion has been implemented earlier using Executor functionality in Java in one of our application. But the number of records were not more that 50k. We are asked to use similar approach. Ruled out implementation using Spring Batch

I am looking for the possible features that need to be considered  in  Java 8 / MySQL DB .

Java 8 : Multithreading using Executor , Completable Future for Async Processing , Streaming

MySQL : Creating Indexes …

Answer (score 1):

- Doing anything to 10M rows will take a long time, and may cause a timeout.
- If you are storing into MySQL, you are stuck with `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`.
- Be sure to declare the datatype to be at least a little larger than the source.  (`SELECT MAX(LENGTH(col)) FROM tbl`) would give you the max length.)
- Consider creating a new table, converting the data as you copy it, plus other columns, into the new table.  Then test that.
- Consider iterating through the table 1000 rows at a time, using the `PRIMARY KEY`, if practical, to keep track of "where you left off".  (Do not use `OFFSET`.)  More on chunking: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks
- Yes, use some kind of batch insert.  But limit the total size of the batch to, say 1MB.  (16MB is hard to get past.)  This may stop you below the 1K mentioned above.
- The amount of time takes for the entire table won't be much different between doing all at once versus 1K rows at a time.
- It may be worth it to also compress the data as you encrypt it.  This *might* shrink the disk footprint by a factor of 3.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Iterating 1000 rows at a time worked.